# Blazor Server using Azure AD, Call to downstream api returns 401

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-ad-msal

I am having problem calling secured API with DownstreamApi.
The API is constructed with endpoint.map and is protected by RequireAuthorization method.

.Net6, Azure AD, Blazor Server are used.

I followed this tutorial for to setup code and Azure AD.

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-blazor-server/blob/main/WebApp-your-API/MyOrg/README-Incremental.md

This works fine, sample Blazor Server app can call API in controller protected by Authorize attribute.

However, in my case, API is minimal, just protected by RequireAuthorization().

**API to be called**

Startup.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;

namespace WebApi
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
                .Build();
            services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(Configuration);

            services.AddControllers();
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            // I want to call this, but 401 is thrown.
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.Map("/api/mytodo", (context) => context.Response.WriteAsync("success")
                    ).RequireAuthorization();
            });

            // This is original. API is in Controller, protected by Authorize Attribute.
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

appsettings.json

```
{
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": " --- cut ---- .onmicrosoft.com",
    "TenantId": "fced --- cut ---- e3",
    "ClientId": "4900 --- cut ---- 93d98"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

**Blazor client app**

startup.cs can be found here.

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-blazor-server/blob/main/WebApp-your-API/MyOrg/Client/Startup.cs

I modified task add button to call my api.

```
    protected async Task AddTask()
    {
        try
        {
            // This throws Unauthorized error!
            var result = await _downstreamApi.GetForUserAsync<string>(
           "ToDoList",
           options =>
           {
               options.RelativePath = "api/mytodo";
               options.BaseUrl = "https://localhost:44351/";
           });
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            var exe = ex;
        }
        
        // The call to original API works.
        await _downstreamApi.PostForUserAsync("TodoList", toDo);
        Navigation.NavigateTo("todolist");
    }
```

How can I call API that is protected by RequireAuthorization?
In my understanding, token is added automatically by using downstreamapi as mentioned in the link below.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-web-app-call-api-acquire-token?tabs=aspnetcore

Answer (score 0):

OK I got this solved.

I had to add explicitly scope.
Actually I jsut wanted to check if the user is authenticated, but this works. (You don't need to set scope if the API is defined in controller and is protected by Authorize attribute only.)

Startup.cs of client

```
services.AddMicrosofttIdentityWebAppAuthentication(Configuration, "AzureAd")
.EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi()
.AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
services.AddDownstreamApi("ToDoList", Configuration.GetSection("ToDoList"));
```

Razor page of client

```
       var result = await _downstreamApi.GetForUserAsync<string>(
       "ToDoList",
       options =>
       {
           options.RelativePath = "api/mytodo";
           options.BaseUrl = "https://localhost:44351/";
           options.Scopes = new List<string>(){"SCOPE"}
       });
```

Startup.cs of API

```
app.UseEndpoint(endpoints => {
    endpoints.Map("api/mytodo", (context) => context.Response.WriteAsync("success")).RequireAuthorization("SCOPE")
});
```